# How to add another email in Woocommerce orders page and make it so it should receive emails as well?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I wanted to add another email to the order's page in Woocommerce other than the admin email. I want to add it so it should receive the order emails as well. Like both of the emails should receive the order being placed in my store on woocommerce. Or how can I make them both emails default?

Comment: under settings > emails > new order there is an email field. you can enter multiple emails seperated with a comma: info@test.com, other@test.com This will send the new order email for the store owner to both emails.

Comment: But one of them is set to default so it's sending the order to only one email I've mentioned there.

Comment: Ok, This should work! Are you sure the second email isn't being blocked somewhere? have you tried wit different email adresses?